# What should I read before reviewing close/open votes

Tags: discussion, review, close-reasons

I recently crossed the 3k threshold and now have access in the Review Queues to Close/Re-open Votes (I actually have the ability to cast such votes).  My question is simply: what should I read before casting votes?  Obviously I need to read the question/answer and any comments.  But the question is more specifically about site policy--how do you decide when something crosses a threshold of badness/incompleteness that it merits being closed?  Should I just vote to close things that I would have flagged in the Low Quality queue?  There I was a little less worried because I knew someone else would eventually have to vote and decide whether I was right or wrong.  Now, it feels like it is (partly) my job to decide when those flags are right or wrong.

Comment: "Obviously I need to read the question/answer and any comments."Actually  to consider the answer is not *necessary.* Sometimes I do, and you can if you want. But taken strictly, the question should be evaluated on its own merits.

Comment: @quid, I guess I forgot that questions get closed and answers get deleted.  I meant by that, whatever it was that was being reviewed.

Comment: When starting out, I enforced my own personal view of quality on the posts.  Then, after voting, I'd click the "back" button to see how other users have voted.  After doing this for a bit, I got a feeling for where I was being too strict/not.  As I spent more time on Meta, I started to identify certain policies I agreed with/didn't, and enforced those appropriately.